# Related rates of change: what am I doing wrong?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I'm new to derivatives, and I try to solve the following exercise:

> A ground camera is being used to film the lift-off of a rocket from its launch pad. The rocket rises vertically so that its vertical distance $y$, in meters, is related to time $t$, in seconds from launch, by $y=10t^2$. Determine the rate of change of the angle of elevation of the camera $10s$ after the launch if the camera is situated horizontally $600m$ from the launch pad.

So my way of thinking is like this:
The angle of the camera is related to the rocket's height by the following formula:
$$tan(\alpha)=\frac{y(t)}{600meters}=\frac{10t^2}{600}=\frac{1}{60}t^2$$
so
$$\alpha=arctan(\frac{1}{60}t^2)$$
So the rate of change of the angle is:
$$\frac{d\alpha}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}arctan(\frac{1}{60}t^2)=\frac{\frac{1}{60}2t}{1+(\frac{1}{60}t^2)^2}=\frac{120t}{t^4 + 3600}$$
So the rate of change of the angle $10s$ after the launch is:
$$\alpha'(10seconds)=\frac{120*10}{10^4+3600}=0.088 rad/s$$

But the answer on my solution sheet is $0.9 rad/s$, it's a different order of magnitude. Is there an error in the solution sheet or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Your answer looks correct to me.

Comment: I think the answer is just rounded off. Are the answers to the rest of the questions expressed in multiple decimal places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your answer is fine.

Alternative working to check:

$$\tan \alpha = \frac{t^2}{60}$$

$$\sec^2 \alpha \frac{d\alpha}{dt}=\frac{t}{30}$$

$$(\tan^2 \alpha + 1)\frac{d\alpha}{dt}=\frac{t}{30}$$

$$\left(\frac{t^4}{3600}+1 \right)\frac{d\alpha}{dt}=\frac{t}{30}$$

$$(t^4+3600)\frac{d\alpha}{dt}=120t$$

when $t=10$, we do have $$\frac{d\alpha}{dt}=\frac{1200}{13600}=\frac{12}{136}=\frac{3}{34}=0.088$$